# Load, manipulate and save text file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, html, text, fileapi

I've got a text file and want to do some find and replace operations to it inside the browser. Unfortunately my coding experience is just really elementary and complete tutorials about building web apps are far too much input at the moment.

Basically I want to upload the file into the browser, then let javascript do the find-and-replace-thing and finally want to download the changed file again.

I've already read about the HTML5 File API and was actually able to load the text file into the browser. But that is where I'm getting lost. In order to split problems up into smaller ones I thought a good next step would be to download the uploaded file again and finally learn how to put the find-and-replace action in between. But I really don't know how to go further and would appreciate any help.

Thanks so far. Benny

```js
document.getElementById('input-file')
  .addEventListener('change', getFile)

function getFile(event) {
 const input = event.target
  if ('files' in input && input.files.length > 0) {
   placeFileContent(
      document.getElementById('content-target'),
      input.files[0])
  }
}

function placeFileContent(target, file) {
 readFileContent(file).then(content => {
   target.value = content
  }).catch(error => console.log(error))
}

function readFileContent(file) {
 const reader = new FileReader()
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reader.onload = event => resolve(event.target.result)
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error)
    reader.readAsText(file, "windows-1252")
  })
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ANSI" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>Text file manipulator</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Text file manipulator</h1>
     <p>
   <input type="file" id="input-file">
  </p>
  <p>
  <textarea id="content-target" style="width:440px;height:400px;"></textarea>
  </p>  
  </body>
</html>
```

[screenshot of text file uploader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxova.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button and call a function in your JavaScript. Something like

```
<button onclick="downloadText()">Download</button>
```

Being the function

```
function downloadText(){
  var content = document.getElementById('content-target').value;
  var dl = document.createElement('a');
  dl.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + 
  encodeURIComponent(content));
  dl.setAttribute('download', 'text.txt');
  dl.click();
}
```

Inside the function you should be able to do all the modifications you want. If you give more details, I can help you with the replace section of it, but it should be something like the following:

```
content.replace(regex, substitute);
```

More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Working [CodePen](https://codepen.io/juanferrer/pen/ZKdovw?editors=1010)

Comment: Hey Juan, this is great. I didn't imagine that this could be so simple, since I didn't know about all these handy HTML DOM methods, yet. I will try the regex-thing. Anyway it seems to be quite simple too. Cheers

Comment: No worries, we're all learning =].
Just make sure you mark it as answered if it helps you, so that other people can also benefit from it.

Comment: Alright, I will as soon as I have added the regex function.